# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn - Trigger for CheckBox IsChecked Property

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am creating a WPF `DataGrid` control with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` CheckBox which should have the **IsChecked** property set as **true** or **false** depending on a `DataTable` value)...

If the `DataTable` row has the value set as **1**, the `DataGridTemplateColumn`  should be **true** (checked). Otherwise, it will be **false** (unchecked)... by default, every new row will be set as **true**, but I couldn't bind these `CheckBox` rows to my `DataTable` value (which will be **1** or **2**)

I tried the following c# code. It works when I finish the UserControl edition and loop through my `DataTable` to save its values... But, when I set **gridResultados.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView** clearly not checking/unchecking my `CheckBoxes` because there is no binding between the `DataTable` column value (1 or 2) and my  `DataGridTemplateColumn` ... this is my closest approach:

```xml
<DataGrid>
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value?" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked">
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Content" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Content" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```c#
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataTable.Rows[gridResultados.SelectedIndex].SetField(4, 1);
}

private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataTable.Rows[gridResultados.SelectedIndex].SetField(4, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I recommend you not to use `DataTable` in WPF, because we usually use EF in WPF, the `DataTable` is part of ADO.NET and it's old and nearly deprecated.

For your problems, you have somethings to fix involving the Binding and the Trigger. First the implicit `DataContext` in each row here is a `DataRowView`. It's available only for `DataTrigger` to use (not for `Trigger`). So you need to use `DataTrigger` instead to listen to the index `[4]` (which references to the fifth column - the column of CheckBox). Second the `Style` you set is wrong, it should be wrapped in `CheckBox.Style` to make it understand that you set Style for `CheckBox`, not for its `Content`. Third the `Style` Trigger cannot override locally set `IsChecked` (as in your code), in this case the template Trigger can override that, but you can also use a Style Setter to set default value `True` for `IsChecked`.
Here is the code you should have:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value?">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked">
            <CheckBox.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                  <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                  <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [4]}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [4]}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            <CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

BTW, I can see that you use event handler to update the value of the underlying data. But that's not the right way to go in term of MVVM where almost what you need is Binding and related stuff. However that part is yours, you need to research more on that. I think it's enough to end this problem here.

Comment: Hello King King,

It worked as I wanted. I'll do some research to improve my knowledge and my WPF project too... thank you!